# Having trouble to find all files that It doesn't match from particular path and list

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following situation,

In this path I have these files:

```
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000057.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000058.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000059.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000157.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000158.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000159.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000257.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000258.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000259.XML
```

On the other hand, I have the following filenames into a list (actually It's a txt file):

```
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000057.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000058.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000059.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000157.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000158.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000159.XML
```

So, the idea is get only the files don't match. I.E:

```
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000257.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000258.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000259.XML
```

I've tried to use:

```
find ENTRY -name "ORDERNUMBER*" | grep -v "ORDERNUMBER*" Exclude.txt
```

But I'm not getting any files.

Do you have any idea What I am doing wrong?

Comment: do you really meant to use a `batch-file`? Because your examples are in `bash`

Comment: @npocmaka yes, you're right. I've modified the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What

```
grep -v "ORDERNUMBER*" Exclude.txt
```

does is print all lines from `Exclude.txt` that do not match the regular expression `ORDERNUMBER*`. Standard input that comes from the find via the pipe is not read. 
All lines in the file contain the string `ORDERNUMBER`, which matches the pattern, and therefore you get an empty result.

To treat the file as a list of patterns and use stdin as the file from which to match, use

```
find ENTRY -name "ORDERNUMBER" 2>>/dev/null | grep -f Exclude.txt -v
```

as @frank suggested. Or try diff:

```
find ENTRY -name "ORDERNUMBER" 2>>/dev/null | diff Exclude.txt -
```

Answer (score 1):

If you had your first list of files in `1.txt` and your second list in `exclude.txt` you could use the `join` command:

```
join -v 1 1.txt exclude.txt
```

Now we can pass the results of a command straight to `join` using process substitution - i.e. `<()` - giving us:

```
join -v 1 <(find ENTRY -name "ORDERNUMBER*") exclude.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
find _dir_ -type f -exec /bin/bash -c '[[ $(grep -c '{}' filelist.txt) -eq 0 ]] && echo '{} \;
```

where *dir* is whatever directory containing the files.

The find will go through everything in the *dir* directory and process each file found.  The exec in the find runs an inline bash script that greps filelist.txt for the name of the file currently being processed by find.  If that file is not in your filelist.txt file, it gets printed out.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
find ENTRY -name "ORDERNUMBER" 2>>/dev/null | grep -f Exclude.txt -v
```

Comment: I suggest to add option `-F` (Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings (instead of regular expressions)).

Comment: A code only answer is not high quality.   A better answer would explain what the code does and how it solves the problem.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller this is correct, in generally. But there's nothing special in my Answer, and this means every explanation that someone might be missing can be easily obtained through the manpages

Answer (score -1):

You can try with awk :

```
find ENTRY -name "ORDERNUMBER*" | awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' exclude.txt -
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are in the parent of ENTRY directory, this Perl one-liner solution would work.

```
> ls -1 ENTRY/*
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000057.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000058.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000059.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000157.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000158.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000159.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000257.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000258.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000259.XML
> cat entry.txt
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000057.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000058.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000059.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000157.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000158.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000159.XML
> perl -ne 'BEGIN {@f1=qx(ls ENTRY/*);@f2=qx(cat entry.txt);@diff{@f1}=undef;delete @diff{@f2};foreach( keys %diff){print}exit}' 
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000258.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000259.XML
ENTRY/ORDERNUMBER_20181016000257.XML
>
```